# Refresh issue in react routing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I developed a react based application and the router is working fine but when i am doing refresh the route which is not rendering same page which goes to error page or login page.

Tried with React router

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.add some code so we can  get batter understanding about your problem

Comment: I think the question and description needs rephrasing as it is nto clear what an OP wants.